# Excel VBA save file as word document in default folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, save-as

```
Sub Submit_Click()

Dim wApp As Object
Dim wDoc As Object

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True

'Retrieves the word doc template and inserts values from the userform using bookmarks

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\template1.docx ", ReadOnly:=False)
    With wDoc
    .Bookmarks("bookmark1").Range.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark2").Range.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark3").Range.Text = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Bookmarks("bookmark4").Range.Text = Me.TextBox5.Value

'set the default filename

ProposedFileName = Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & "Serial Number" & " " & TextBox1.Value _
& " " & TextBox2.Value & "- RMA" & ".docx"

'trying to save file back to .doc instead of the default .xlms format

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With fd
    .FilterIndex = 2
    .InitialFileName = ProposedFileName
    If .Show Then
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    Else
    Call CommandButton4_Click 'cancel save
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hi all,

My script above is only a partial one that is taken from my userform. Basicall the scenario is my userform opens a word document template and inserts texts in the document from the excel userform using bookmarks.

After I click submit on the userform, the filedialog opens with the default .xlms and does not allow me to save it back to .doc

I have been searching and modifying my script for ages and cannot seem to get it right. I would appreciate if someone can tell me how. Thank you.

Regards,
Kev

Comment: If your VBA macro in Excel opens a Word template and fill it, it's the Word template that you should save as .doc and not the Excel file. In your code above, you need to show how you open the Word template (you will probably store it in a variable, say `myWordTemplate`. It's on that variable you have to call the `SaveAs2` method to show the right format (`myWordTemplate.SaveAs2`).

Comment: P.s. by the way this question is an exact duplicate of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53139254/3111149), I'm flagging it as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Save file as Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139254/vba-save-file-as-word-document)

Comment: I have amended the post to include the whole script

Comment: @Matteo NNZ, I had to create another post to help better understand my script. Sorry

Comment: @MatteoNNZ can you explain how I need to add the open word template into a variable please?

Comment: No, you use the [edit] link below a question to improve it - don't clutter the site by re-posting a question, please!

Comment: Also, you need to post code that will *compile* if there aren't error messages. The code above won't even compile - it's missing (for example) and `End With`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()  

'set default file name and file path
ProposedFileName = Format(Now(), "DDMMMYYYY") & " " & TextBox1.Value & "-" & TextBox2.Value & ".doc"
ProposedFilePath = "C:\Users\"

    'save the word document called by excel to a .doc format
    With wApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
      wDoc.SaveAs2 ProposedFilePath & ProposedFileName, _
      FilterIndex = 1, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
    End With

'unloads the userforms and .doc file after the document is saved
Unload Me
wApp.Quit

'a dialog box pops up after document is saved to say where the file is saved since I was't unable to implement the browse folder option
  MsgBox "The document is saved in " & ProposedFilePath, vbOKOnly
  Cancel = False
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Hi All, 
Thank you for the help. I have managed to solve my problem with the above code but unfortunately could not do it with the browse location dialog box. I hope this will become useful for everyone who needs it.

However, if anyone knows how to implement the browse folder location with this code will be better and useful for others.